# Is time.sleep() enough to safely create a delay for a simple webscraper?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using a webscraping code, without a headless browser, in order to scrape about 500 inputs from Transfer Mrkt for a personal project.

According to best practices, I need to randomize the web scraping pattern I have, [along with using a delay and dealing with errors/loading delays,](https://www.scrapehero.com/how-to-prevent-getting-blacklisted-while-scraping/) in order to successfully scrape Transfer Markt without getting raising any flags.

I understand how Selenium and Chromedriver can help with all of these in order to scrape more safely, but I've used requests and BeautifulSoup to create a much simpler webscraper:

```
import requests, re, ast
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup import pandas as pd
i = 1
url_list = []
while True:

   page = requests.get('https://www.transfermarkt.us/spieler-statistik/wertvollstespieler/marktwertetop?page=' + str(i), headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}).text
parsed_page = BeautifulSoup(page,'lxml')

   all_links = []
for link in parsed_page.find_all('a', href=True): link = str(link['href']) all_links.append(link)
   r = re.compile('.*profil/spieler.*')
player_links = list(filter(r.match, all_links))

for plink in range(0,25):
    url_list.append('https://www.transfermarkt.us' + player_links[plink])

   i += 1
if i > 20: break
final_url_list = []
for i in url_list:
int_page = requests.get(i, headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}).text
parsed_int_page = BeautifulSoup(int_page,'lxml')

   graph_container = parsed_int_page.find('div', class_='large-7 columns small-12 marktwertentwicklung-graph')
graph_a = graph_container.find('a')
graph_link = graph_a.get('href')

   final_url_list.append('https://www.transfermarkt.us' + graph_link)


for url in final_url_list:
    r = requests.get('https://www.transfermarkt.com/neymar/marktwertverlauf/spieler/68290', headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
    p = re.compile(r"'data':(.*)}\],")
    s = p.findall(r.text)[0]
    s = s.encode().decode('unicode_escape')
    data = ast.literal_eval(s)

#rest of the code to write scraped info below this
```

I was wondering if this is generally considered a safe enough way to scrape a website like Transfer Mrkt if I add the time.sleep() method from the time library, as detailed [here](https://blog.hartleybrody.com/web-scraping-cheat-sheet/#delays-and-backing-off), in order to create a delay - long enough to allow the page to load, like 10 seconds - to scrape the 500 inputs successfully without raising any flags.

I would also forego using randomized clicks (which I think can only be done with selenium/chromedriver) to mimic human behavior, and was wondering if that too would be ok to exclude in order to scrape safely.

Comment: Not what you're asking, but the problem with `time.sleep` is it ties up the thread. If in the future you want to do multiple requests at once, you'll need to start multiple threads just to handle each. Using asyncio might be a better choice.

Comment: This seems excessive. For 500 pages, I'd just give it a try with no time delay. You can also put a time delay if an error is raised with `try` and `except`.

Comment: "Safe" is a relative term. I'm voting to close as opinion based, primarily due to the fact that, unless you happen to get a web security employee of that particular website in the answers, it's unlikely that we would be able to provide a meaningful answer as to what constitutes a minimum level of obfuscation to not be detected as a scraper

Comment: @Carcigenicate, do mind clarifying what you mean by 'thread'?

Comment: @exlo You'll probably want to read up on threads. Going down the road you are here, they may become useful soon. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)) has a good run down. Basically, if you want to have multiple things happening at the same time, you need multiple threads of execution going at once (or multiple processes). All programs start with a main thread that code runs on. You can start new threads if you need to to do multiple things at the same time.